# How can I find all the documents that starts with a certain number

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, nosql

```
{
    "_id":ObjectId("92837261829"),
    "num":12
}
{
    "_id":ObjectId("d4372643229"),
    "num":25
}
```

What would be the mongodb syntax to get the document where "num" starts with a 1.

Note that value in "num" is a number not a string. So I guess db.collectionName.find({"num":{$regex:/1.*/}}) or something like this might not work.

the output of the syntax should be

```
{
"_id":ObjectId("92837261829"),
"num":12
}
```

Comment: how many Documents you have in your collection?

Answer (score 1):

You can actually check the [`$substr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/) of the first character to see if it matches:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { "$redact": {
     "$cond": {
       "if": { "$eq": [ { "$substr": [ "$num", 0, 1 ] }, "1" ] },
       "then": "$$KEEP",
       "else": "$$PRUNE"
     }
   }}
])
```

The logical condition is sent to [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/), which uses the "ternary" to take the action to either `$$KEEP` or `$$PRUNE` the document from the results.

From MongoDB 3.4 that should be replaced with either [`$substrCP`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substrCP/) or [`$substrBytes`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substrBytes/), as the former operator is deprecated and now aliases [`$substrBytes`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substrBytes/).

Alternately you can do the same thing with [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/), albeit a little slower due to JavaScript evaluation:

```
db.collection.find(function() {
  return this.num.toString().substr(0,1) === "1";
})
```

Note that both methods are doing a calculation and therefore must scan the full collection in order to get a result. So in production environments this is not a practical operation to do.

In production it would be better advised to store such a thing as a separate property, then you can query it directly and utilize and index to speed search results.